# Python Control library step_info returning nan for all parameters

Tags: python

I am running the following code:

```
import control as c

kc = 0.9*3/23
d = c.pade(0.3)
Gp = c.tf([1],[1,1])*c.tf(d[0],d[1])
ti = 1
Gc = kc*c.tf([ti, 1], [ti, 0])
sys1 = Gc*Gp/(1+Gc*Gp)
data1 = c.step_info(sys1)
print(data1)
```

And the data I get is all nan. And the problem is not in the closed loop system, because when I run this in Matlab it returns what would seem as the correct results. Anyone knows what could be going wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does the current code return segmentation fault as an error?

Comment: @medium-dimensional I'm not sure I understand the question. But it seems to run fine, the issue is the output with the parameters of the response profile due to a unit step in the closed loop transfer function I defined in the code are: {'RiseTime': nan, 'SettlingTime': nan, 'SettlingMin': nan, 'SettlingMax': nan, 'Overshoot': nan, 'Undershoot': nan, 'Peak': inf, 'PeakTime': inf, 'SteadyStateValue': nan}. Where things as RiseTime, or Settling time should definitely not be nan, given that the plot for the output profile shows that the response is stable.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! The code returned a segmentation fault for me so I need to look in to that first. :)